# Capture http post from browser

Tags: http, vb6, http-post

How to capture http post data from a browser in VB6? Just like [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/ro/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) addon for Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Please don't put "[vb6]" into the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: From what point of view?

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  By far, the best tool I've used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but it's how you would do it in .net

[A list of Request Objects (server variables)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/request_server_variables.aspx)